# How to organize scatter points sequentially in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a simplified example of the data I'm working with:

```
x <- c("before", "before", "before", "before", "after","after","after","after")
y <- c(22, 25, 26, 27, 45, 67, 89, 74)
z <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C")
data <- data.frame(x,y,z)
```

And here is my code for ggplot2:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y, color=z, shape=z)) + geom_jitter()
```

The graph ends up looking like this:

[image: The graph ends up looking like this]

How can I get the points for the individuals A,B,C (variable Z) to be plotted sequentially along the x-axis? For example, above the categorical variable "after", I want to see all the points for individual B jittered, and then all the points for individual C jittered next to it instead of points for both mixing together? I haven't been able to find any examples online of how to do something like this.

To further clarify, here is an example of what I want my graph to end up looking like

[image: here is an example of what I want my graph to end up looking like]

Answer (score 0):

To call twice `geom_jitter`, the 2nd with `y=0` will put the points at the same height but the jitter amount is computed twice, the `x` coordinates are not the same.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y, color=z, shape=z)) + 
  geom_jitter() +
  geom_jitter(aes(y = 0)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: To clarify, I want each individual represented in the Z variable to be be separated in each category on the x-axis, similar to the second figure I added in my original post. So for example in the "after" category, jittering all points representing individual A, followed by B, etc. so instead of the points for all individuals overlapping, they're shown side by side. Is there a way to do that in ggplot? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**Offsetting by category**

To get sequential ordering, group by the `z` variable. This will give `x` category a subcategory `z`

```
ggplot2::ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y, group=z, color=z, shape=z)) + geom_jitter()
```

[image]

**To sort `before` and `after` in different order:**

Your `x` variable is a categorical variable, which ggplot automatically sorts alphabetically. To override this alphabetic sorting, you must define your variable as a `factor`:

```
x <- c("before", "before", "before", "before", "after","after","after","after")
x <- factor(x, levels = c("before", "after"))
y <- c(22, 25, 26, 27, 45, 67, 89, 74)
z <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C")
data <- data.frame(x,y,z)
```

This effectively gives `before` the value `1` and `after` the value `2`, so that the sorting behaviour yields the right order on the x-axis.

Comment: I tried grouping the Z variable to get sequential ordering with my own dataset but the points for each individual still seem to overlap. Is there a way to get it so that the points for each individual in Z don't cross over into another individual's space, similar to how the red and green points in "before" don't overlap? In "after" on the x-axis, the two green points still fall in between the two blue points. Thanks in advance.